# Cabal: Failed to Install GLUtil

Tags: haskell, opengl, c-preprocessor, cabal-install

I'm new to Haskell but I want to try and write some OpenGL experiments in it.
I've successfully installed OpenGL, GLUT and a few other packages but when I attempt to install GLUtil I get the following error:

```
Building GLUtil-0.9.0.1...
Failed to install GLUtil-0.9.0.1
Build log ( C:\Users\David\AppData\Roaming\cabal\logs\GLUtil-0.9.0.1.log ):
Building GLUtil-0.9.0.1...
Preprocessing library GLUtil-0.9.0.1...
hpp: Couldn't open input file: -includeC:\Users\David\AppData\Local\Temp\ghc3236_0\ghc_2.h
CallStack (from HasCallStack):

error, called at src\Hpp\CmdLine.hs:89:0: error:
    22 in hpp-0.3.0.0-61vdEFyxUJDaeEBxsHCsL:Hpp.CmdLine
`hpp' failed in phase `C pre-processor'. (Exit code: 1)
cabal: Leaving directory 'C:\Users\David\AppData\Local\Temp\cabal-tmp-6356\GLUtil-0.9.0.1'
cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
GLUtil-0.9.0.1 failed during the building phase. The exception was:
ExitFailure 1
```

I tried using older versions of GLUtil and its dependencies but it always ended the same way and I eventually just cleared and reinstalled the Haskell Platform (I didn't know about sandboxing).

One thing that stands out is that `-includeC:\Users\Dav...` looks to me like a typo, as if there should be a space between `-include` and `C:\...` but I don't know how to change this. I couldn't find `CmdLine.hs`, just the interface file `CmdLine.hi` which yielded no results.

Does anyone have any advice on how to remedy this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that there should be a space between the `-include` and the file name.

I created a version of GLUtil-0.9.0.1 that is already preprocessed and should work for you:

https://github.com/erantapaa/GLUtil-0.9.0.1-no-cpp

It assumes you are using GHC 7.10.x or later.

The steps to remove the dependency on CPP were:

- files JuicyTextures.hs and ShaderProgram.hs just use CPP to include Control.Applicative for older versions of GHC, so I just commented out those lines. Also remove `CPP` from the `LANGUAGE` pragma.
- Linear.hs uses CPP to generate code. You can create the pre-processed output with:

  ```
  gcc -E - < Linear.hs > new-Linear.hs
  ```

Then remove lines beginning with a hash (#) and remove `CPP` from the `LANGUAGE` pragma.

- in `GLUtil.cabal` comment out/remove the lines:

  ```
  if impl(ghc >= 7.10.1)
    Build-depends:     hpp >= 0.3 && < 0.4
    GHC-Options:       -pgmPhpp -optP--cpp -optP-P
  else
    Build-tools:       cpphs
    GHC-Options:       -pgmPcpphs -optP--cpp -optP
  ```

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you! The only question I still have is how is it that there came to be a lack of space after the `include`?

Comment: Don't know, and I don't have a Windows system right now to debug it.